# Retrieve rows in crm2011 subgrid with JScript

Tags: dynamics-crm, javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

As an JScript newbie, I have a problem with a subgrid in MS CRM 2011.

I have a form with a subgrid and in OnSave of that form, I want to loop over all the rows in the subgrid.

How can I do this with JScript ? Or is it possible another way, ex plugin ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code which you can do on save of the form

```
var gridControl = document.getElementById('grdrelatedcontacts').control;
for (var intRowNumber = 0; intRowNumber < gridControl.getRecordsFromInnerGrid().length; intRowNumber++)
    for (var intCellNumber = 0; intCellNumber < gridControl.getRecordsFromInnerGrid()[intRowNumber][3].cells.length; intCellNumber++)
        alert(gridControl.getRecordsFromInnerGrid()[intRowNumber][3].cells[intCellNumber].outerText);
```

Comment: how does one know that the id is 'grdrelatedcontacts'? ie where do i get the id for my grid from????

Comment: grdrelatedContact is the grid name which you can find when you are on the form customization , just click on the grid and you will find the name of the grid

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the subgrid values on save by doing the following:

```
var gridControl = document.getElementById('subgrid_id').control;
var ids = gridControl.get_allRecordIds();
for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var cellValue = gridControl.getCellValue('column_name', ids[i]);
    // logic
}
```

Doing this on load is a bit more challenging since subgrids are loaded asynchronously and aren't likely to be done loading when the form onload event fires. You can check the grid periodically though to see when it's done loading by calling a function like the following in your form onload:

```
function subGridOnload() {
    var grid = document.getElementById('subgrid_id');
    if (grid.readyState!="complete") {
        // delay one second and try again.  
        setTimeout(subGridOnload, 1000);
        return;
    }

    // logic
}
```

Comment: It will return only Ids of the records present in 1st page right..? What about Ids of the records present in the next page of the sub grid?

Comment: This only returns 1st page, precisely what the OP was trying to get around

Answer (score 0):

Use a Rest call and retrieve the corresponding records :S

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/pws_streedandhousenodatas?$filter=_pws_streetandhousenumberid_value eq " + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(), true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var pws_streedandhousenodataid = results.value[i]["pws_streedandhousenodataid"];
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

In this case the Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId() get you your current record id and you are looking all the lookups (that are in the sub-grid), you can also add some fields to select more info from them.