# MSCRM2011 How retrieve Subgrid Data

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, jscript, subgrid

how to retrive all rows from SUBGRID using Jscript

i have one entity "E-mail" which contain one subgrid "attachmentsGrid"

now i need to retrive all the attachment size and total it up then show in a field....

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You Can Refer this links [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347083/retrieve-rows-in-crm2011-subgrid-with-jscript),[Link2](http://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/retrieve-subgrid-rows-in-crm-2011-using-jscript/)