# CRM 2015 Online Update 1: Get SubGrid rows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347083/retrieve-rows-in-crm2011-subgrid-with-jscript), [this](http://mehmetgunen.com/crm-2013-subgrid-javascript-operations/) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27fea949-c332-4263-bb46-d990a18008b8(v=crm.7)#BKMK_subgridAddOnLoad)

The goal is to read the subgrid rows in JavaScript in order to get the guids of the rows which could be used in later on. This is done in `OnLoad` of the form.

There are a couple of issues here:

1. When I use the `addOnLoad` method, it does not call the handler when
   the form is loaded for the first time. The Grid has to be refreshed
   or sorted for it to fire the event. Even if I execute the code in OnLoad event, it shows zero rows in the grid although the `Xrm.Page.getControl("Idebarare").getGrid()` is not null.
2. When it is fired, `getTotalRecordCount` returns -1

   `Xrm.Page.getControl("Idebarare").getGrid().getTotalRecordCount()`

This is the code I'm using at the moment. Here I'm calling `GetContacts` from the form's onLoad.

```
function GetContacts(){

Xrm.Page.getControl("Idebarare").addOnLoad(myContactsGridOnloadFunction);


}

function myContactsGridOnloadFunction(){
var allGridEntities = [];
var rows = Xrm.Page.getControl("Idebarare").getGrid().getRows();
rows.forEach(function (row, i) {
 allGridEntities.push(row.getData().getEntity());
});


}
```

So the question is how to get the rows for getting attributes/guids from a subgrid in JavaScript in Dynamics CRM 2015 Update 1 online?

Comment: I think the issue you're experiencing here is related to the async loading nature of the grids. Have you tried explicitly calling the .refresh method after adding the onload handler? I know it's not really clean to force a Grid refresh during the form onload, but I think it might do the trick.